# Different sized pneumatic Pistons

Tags: forces, air

If two different sized pneumatic pistons have the same amount of air pressure, will they exert the same amount of force? If not, would a bigger or smaller piston have more force? And an explanation please.

edit: if both Pistons have the same pressure behind them, does the size change the total force of the piston?

Comment: Smaller in what sense?

Comment: You mean with different area? Force is pressure times area.

Comment: Yes smaller / bigger surface area that's pushing

Comment: Well then you can answer it yourself. Just suppose one piston has a surface area of 1 square centimeter, and the other is the size of a football field, and the air pressure on each one is the same *per square centimeter*. Suppose each one is actually a suction cup. Which would be harder to lift?

Comment: So the overall force would be larger? If you make it a complete answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressure is force per unit area. A larger piston with the same pressure has more surface area and thus a larger total force.

Think of it microscopically. Pressure is the the force of all the gas particles averaged over the wall area of the container. To get the same pressure in two differently sized boxes you need to "compensate" for the larger area by injecting more gas particles. More particles of identical mass bumping into the walls at the same speed equates to on average a larger total force when you sum all the collisions at any particular time.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, force is in *pounds*, but pressure is in pounds *per square inch*.

So for example, the wings on heavy airplanes have to have *more square inches*, i.e. be bigger.

Pistons are no different. At same pressure, force is proportional to area.

Comment: edited the question based on the terminology, if you could try and help me with it please

Comment: @TwoShorts_: I don't know what else to say. At the same pressure, force is proportional to area.